# convert href to a base64 version of the file

Tags: javascript, base64

I have an anchor point.

```
<a id='clicktodownload' href='/getfile?yadayadayada' download='1.3.6.1.2.3.4.111.234'>
```

I can successfully grab the anchor

```
document.querySelector('clicktodownload')
```

I can download it either by clicking it with a mouse, or:

```
document.querySelector('clicktodownload').click()
```

This "thing" in this anchor can be of type pdf, or zipped file, or any other type of file.  It is unknown.

Is it possible to get the base64 representation of the file when downloaded **without actually downloading it** and setting it in memory in javascript?

All I need is to set a variable to it, but without actually triggering a download.

jQuery can be used, but unfortunately fetch cannot.  This needs to be ie11 compatible.

If more information is needed, just ask.  Thank you.

Comment: also would like to add, jquery usage is fine, but fetch() is not unfortunately as this needs to work in ie

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments below it.  One answer would be to use an XmlHttpRequest (aka AJAX).

Comment: Forcing `.click()` on a file input won't work in some Browsers. But really, you should limit the file type. You're taking files you don't even know what they are? What are you trying to do with them? If you mean you want to view the file with JavaScript, without loading onto your Server, there's the File Reader API. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) out.

Comment: updated the question @DaveS

Comment: @PHPglue I don't want to explain the reasons behind why I want to achieve the above, only discuss whether it is possible or not.  What I am looking for is a way to just get the binary data of the file without having to download the file in memory.

Comment: I don't think that `document.querySelector('clicktodownload')` would pick up that anchor. It would have to be `document.querySelector('#clicktodownload')`... and no, there is no way to get the contents of a file without getting contents of the file.

Comment: Can we assume the file is stored on the same domain than the script and that there is no cross-origin issue? Also, can we assume that when you say *without downloading it*, you actually mean without saving to disk?

Comment: Yes to both questions @Kaiido

Comment: Downloads don't save to the Client's Computer, until the Client allows it. If you just want to read a file with JavaScript, use the File Reader API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is served from the same-domain and that there is no cross-origin requests, then you can simply make an XMLHttpRequest to the `href` value, and request the response to be a Blob:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', clicktodownload.href);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = processResponse;
xhr.send();
```

This will return a Blob, with its `type` set to whatever the server sends as responseType, so if it is important to get the correct type, be sure your server knows what it sends.

Now, I would advice you work directly with the returned Blob, e.g, if you want to display it in say an `<iframe>`, you could do

```
function processResponse(evt) {
  var blob = evt.target.result;
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  iframe.src = url;
  // don't forget to call URL.revokeObjecURL(iframe.src) when not needed anymore
}
```

But if you **really** need the b64 version (e.g to include it in a standalone document like svg), then you can use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

Comment: I was working on exactly the same method as you posted this, but was getting the data back as an array buffer, and was curious if i could conform it to base64.  THANK YOU

Comment: This works!  console.logging the blob I am getting:   Blob(2402581) {size: 2402581, type: "application/x-7z-compressed"}
size
:
2402581
type
:
"application/x-7z-compressed"
__proto__
:
Blob